# Start function not being called C#

Tags: c#, function, class, unity-game-engine, properties

I get a component like this

```
GameObject currentAuraObject
IAura currentAura = currentAuraObject.GetComponent<IAura>();
```

where current aura is

```
public class AirAura : MonoBehaviour, IAura
{
    public ElementalIncreament DamageElementalIncreament { get; set; }
    public ElementalIncreament ResistanceElementalIncreament { get; set; }
    public ElementalIncreament EnemyElementIncreament { get; set; }

    private void Start()
    {
        DamageElementalIncreament = new ElementalIncreament(ElementalIncreament.ElementalType.Air, 20);
        ResistanceElementalIncreament = new ElementalIncreament(ElementalIncreament.ElementalType.Air, 15);
        EnemyElementIncreament = new ElementalIncreament(ElementalIncreament.ElementalType.Earth, 35);
    }
}
```

the variable `currentAura` itself is not null but all the properties are.. I don't understand why the `Start` function is not being called and initialise the properties properly, how can I fix this ?

Comment: So if you out Debug.Log("here"); in the Start, nothing comes up in console? And the script is attached to some gameobject in scene?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Awake isn't triggered too neither Update is.

Comment: If you make new empty scene, attach default empty script with Start() + Debug.Log(), then add the script into gameobject, press play, still nothing?

Comment: I've had this problem before and yes it will still play nothing.

Comment: And console log messages are enabled?

Comment: Yes.. they are enabled i even ran a debugger.

Comment: Have you attached the script to an object yet? This is the how-to:
https://docs.unity3d.com/401/Documentation/Manual/Scripting.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have a function automatically called in your class you need to create a class contructor like below (the function has to be public, have no return type and be the same name as your class):

```
public AirAura()
    {
        DamageElementalIncreament = new ElementalIncreament(ElementalIncreament.ElementalType.Air, 20);
        ResistanceElementalIncreament = new ElementalIncreament(ElementalIncreament.ElementalType.Air, 15);
        EnemyElementIncreament = new ElementalIncreament(ElementalIncreament.ElementalType.Earth, 35);
    }
```

Comment: While this is **somehow** correct. In Unity, **don't** use the constructor function if your script inherits from `MonoBehaviour`.In this case, it does.  You do your initialization in the `Awake` and `Start` functions. Maybe changing the `Start` to `Awake` would have solved this problem.